# Adding Javascript function to already initialized dataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a bunch of HTML tables that use dataTables and Highcharts.

I have a live example here.

```
https://live.datatables.net/bituyelo/8/
```

I want to add radial buttons to the web page that perform some high level searches. In my example, I want to click 'All" or "Succeeded" or "Failed" or "Aborted".

I found the info I needed to do it here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554090/showing-all-data-with-filter-from-checkbox-value-in-datatable
```

But I already have some javascript initializing the table. So when I add the javascript function from the above article, the table initializes twice.

I'm afraid I do not know Javascript.
How do I make the function work with my already existing code?

In my example, the values I am looking at are in column 6, (counting from 0). Column 6 is a hidden column.

I placed the javascript in question, at the bottom of the javascript window.